# Audience Definition / Estimated Daily Results

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api, target-audience

When creating a campaign and an AdSet using the Facebook web interface, you are given Audience Definition (Specific to Broad) and Estimated Daily results e.g. Reach and Landing Page Views...

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POrg8.png)

is there a way to obtain this information via their API - I've been calling Delivery Estimate, but only get the Potential Reach in the results.

Tried /deliveryestimate but not 100% sure this is the right call to make.

```
curl -G -d 'optimization_goal=IMPRESSIONS' -d 'access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN' https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/ADSET_ID/delivery_estimate
```

> {"data":[{"daily_outcomes_curve":[{"spend":0,"reach":0,"impressions":0,"actions":0}],"estimate_dau":14681,"estimate_mau":15000,"estimate_ready":true}]}